# How to get child products from Layer Class Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, layered-navigation, product-collection

`14219` is the ID of the parent product. `14217, 14218` are the child product ids, I need to get from the Layer which products visibility is  `VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE` , can anyone help?
Thanks

```
class Layer extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer {

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = parent::getProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
    $idArray = [14219,14217, 14218];
    if (!empty($idArray)) {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ["in"=>$idArray]);
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

}

Comment: Isn't parent visible?

Comment: I tried to set parent visible and removed parent id from array but didn't get children

Comment: I think the collection has been loaded before you add the filter.